# Deleting from table with Same Table foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, sql-delete

I'm trying to run this sql server statement:

```
delete C from Company C, Company D where C.CompanyID > 1310 AND C.CompanyID != D.ParentID
```

I'm getting the following sql error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_Company_Company". The conflict occurred in database "DevelopmentDB", table "dbo.Company", column 'ParentID'.

I checked and there are no companies where ParentID = CompanyID. I'm curious why my delete statement isn't filtering out the companies that would cause this constraint to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

Have you verified the results of your attempt with something like this to ensure that what you are attempting to delete is what you actually intend to delete?

```
select C.<field list> from Company C, Company D 
where C.CompanyID > 1310 AND C.CompanyID != D.ParentID
```

You might also try the delete statement using a sub query approach.  It might make it easier to logically identify that the query you are running is what you are actually intending.

However, I always recommend testing with a select first for verification.

So running (*if this is your intended results - modify if not*):

```
Select <field list> FROM Company WHERE CompanyID > 1310 
AND CompanyID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ParentID FROM Company)
```

Before running (*again, this is just an example*).:

```
DELETE Company WHERE CompanyID > 1310 
AND CompanyID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ParentID FROM Company)
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 rows for the 2nd query you wrote, which confuses me. If that were the case then a constraint wouldn't be the issue, and 0 rows would be affected.

Comment: Zero rows means that any companyid's that are > 1310 DO HAVE companyId's that are also parentID's.  You can try the select statement without the subquery to verify existence of companyid's greater than 1310.

Comment: Could you update your question with the specific flavor of sql we're talking about here.  TSQL, PLSQL, Postgres, etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error ("The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint ...") in a situation where I had a table with columns and data like:

```
| RecordID | ParentRecordID | (other fields...) |
|----------|----------------|-------------------|
|        1 |           null |               ... |   
|        2 |              1 |               ... |
```

The error hit when my DELETE command tried to delete record 1 before record 2.  The same-table foreign key constraint that had been set up on column `ParentRecordID` pointing at column `RecordID` prevented the delete: It wouldn't have been valid for record 2 to be pointing at record 1 when record 1 didn't exist anymore.

I worked around the problem by deleting records with a non-null `ParentRecordID` value first:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE ParentRecordID IS NOT null
  AND (other criteria...)
```

Then I could proceed to delete the remaining records with an additional DELETE statement:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE (other criteria...)
```

Comment: I donot think this would work if there is multiple heirarchy.